# Show Username on Windows Form

Tags: adfs, web-to-winforms

I have an MSI package which gets launched from a website. This MSI package is a winform application acting like a WebAPI which receives Ajax request from the website.

I want to show the Username of the user logged in the website, as the title bar of the launched winform application (say e.g. in Visual Studio, where the logged in user name is shown above the top right corner).

I have come to know that this can be achieved via ADFS etc., but I am new to that.

So any recommended approaches/examples or ways to achieve the above?.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate via ADFS, you need to setup an ADFS claims rule to pass "Display Name" as a claim in the token.

When you receive the token, extract the value of this claim and display it.